# Is there a difference between using NSURLConnection with delegate call backs and sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:?

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I'd like to understand what the difference is between using `–initWithRequest:delegate:` with delegate methods and `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`.

Are there some performance differences based on the number of requests, or any other criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler` is an easier call to make. `initWithRequest:delegate` gives you more control over things like caching, redirects, downloading large or incremental amounts of data, canceling requests, etc, etc.